# Ambari storm sink issue

Tags: apache-storm, ambari

I am getting below error while my storm topology gets first message from kafka and worker dies.

```
2015-08-13 12:44:58 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Finished loading executor hdfs-bolt:[3 3]
2015-08-13 12:44:58 b.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate a class listed in config under section topology.metrics.consumer.register with fully qualified name org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink
at backtype.storm.metric.MetricsConsumerBolt.prepare(MetricsConsumerBolt.java:46) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.3-1.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.3-1]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__6414$fn__6427.invoke(executor.clj:732) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.3-1.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.3-1]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__451.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.6.3-1.jar:0.9.3.2.2.6.3-1]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does your jar file contain the missing file? How do you assembly your jar?

Comment: No, I am not seeing any jar file with this particular class. Ambari HDP installation suppose to add ambari-metrics-storm-sink.jar under /storm/lib directory. But for some reason I am not seeing this jar. How I can get this jar file ?

Comment: Dud you try to download from central maven repository web page?

Comment: yes, I tried but no luck.

Comment: You you can compile your topology, right? So the file is at your computer. So either, the file is contained in a local jar (maybe with different name) or you need to include the file into the jar you submit to Storm.

Comment: Which version of HDP stack are you using? It should be HDP 2.2.4 or later. [Ambari document](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.1.0/bk_upgrading_Ambari/content/_moving_from_ganglia_to_ambari_metrics.html) says "If you are using HDP 2.2 Stack, Storm metrics will not work with Ambari Metrics until you are upgraded to HDP 2.2.4 or later."

Comment: I have HDP 2.2.6.3 installed. But I solved this issue by adding manually ambari-storm-sink jar into storm/lib.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the version of Ambari installed with "rpm -qa | grep ambari" and check "/usr/lib/storm/lib" for all hosts for the ambari metrics jar matching the version
- Example: ambari-metrics-storm-sink-with-common-2.0.0.151.jar
- Run "yum reinstall ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink" on all storm supervisor nodes
- Restart the supervisors and re-deploy the topology
- Check "/usr/lib/storm/lib" to ensure that the matching ambari version jar is present

Hortonworks has posted a knowledge base article on exactly this issue: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/49117/storm-worker-fails-with-javalangclassnotfoundexcep.html

In my case, I needed to install (not reinstall) ambari-metrics-hadoop-sink as it was not installed by default on the HDP sandbox.